# Soundcloud embed issue

Tags: html, soundcloud

I am having a minor problem when using the soundcloud embed code on my wordpress site.

Its working fine, its just it shows the artist username and the track, I just want it to show the track name.

Here is my code

```
<iframe width="106%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/users/63156530&amp;color=6f0025&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
```

If you see the image below, you can see why I want to do this.
http://gyazo.com/693c03cd588c61a056001eced99952ff

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
<iframe width="106%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/users/63156530&amp;color=6f0025&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=true&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
```

That should work. For the next time, this is more related with HTML than with Wordpress